# How to iterate over Object's property-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a structure like this:

```
var myMap = {
    partnr1: ['modelA', 'modelB', 'modelC'],
    partnr2: ['modelA', 'modelB', 'modelC']
};
```

I am going to iterate through each of the elements (partnr) with their associatives (models).

I am trying a double `$each()` iteration in order to achieve this, but nothing happens:

```
$.each(myMap, function (i, val) {
    $.each(i, function (innerKey, innerValue) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#variant').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).text(innerKey + "-" + innerValue).fadeIn("slow");

            });

        }, i * 6000);

    });
});
```

The effect with fading in and out that I am trying to achieve is working fine when using a single value array (`Object`), but not when I need to have more than one value for each key like here.

How to accomplish this iteration successfully? Are there other ways than using an `Object` that would be better in this case?

Answer (score 173):

An answer to your Question from 2019:

It depends on what version of ECMAScript you use.

**Pre ES6:**

Use any of the answers below, e.g.:

```
for (var m in myMap){
    for (var i=0;i<myMap[m].length;i++){
    ... do something with myMap[m][i] ...
    }
}
```

**For ES6 (ES 2015):**

You should use a `Map` object, which has the `entries()` function:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("0", "foo");
myMap.set(1, "bar");
myMap.set({}, "baz");

for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

**For ES8 (ES 2017):**

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) was introduced:

```
const object = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: I want to ask a stupid question, why use the ES8 when end User could be on an older browser?

Comment: @Erik: JS development also happens in fields other than web development. There, you may not have to worry about older browser version and can enjoy the improvements ES8 brings.

Comment: @Erik transpilers like babel help convert from newer versions of js to older versions of js. So even if the user is on an older browser, our transpiled ES8 code still runs on the older browser.

Comment: After the latest edit (Dec 10, 2021), the third method is a duplicate of the ES6 snippet.

The previous version using Object.entries was correct, as it was showing how to iterate over a vanilla javascript object used as a map, instead of the ES6 Map type.

Comment: Thanks @TristanMacKinlay. I reverted this edit

Comment: Mozila page says Chrome supports Object.entries but then why doesn't Object.entries(myMap) work when i ran on the original myMap example, like below?

var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("0", "foo");
myMap.set(1, "bar");
myMap.set({}, "baz");

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myMap)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}

Comment: Oh I see, 3rd example is for a regular object created as a map vs a true Map type.

Answer (score 48):

I'd use standard javascript:

```
for (var m in myMap){
    for (var i=0;i<myMap[m].length;i++){
    ... do something with myMap[m][i] ...
    }
}
```

Note the different ways of treating objects and arrays.

Comment: Why? And you omitted the necessary closure…

Comment: It's quicker and in my opinion cleaner. And I skipped the rest because it's unclear to me what it's supposed to do. What is #variant? What should #variant end up doing?

Comment: #variant is an id of a div that is going to be showed (faded in) with the info from the map. For each partnr there should be faded in a list with the corrensponding models.

Answer (score 42):

**Functional Approach for ES6+**

If you want to take a more functional approach to iterating over the `Map` object, you can do something like this

```js
const myMap = new Map() 
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    console.log(value, key)
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, it looks like this old JQuery thread has been coopted by **[ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** users.

If this is what you're looking for, may I suggest using the `Array.from()` function which converts the `Map` to an `Array`. This allows you to easily chain transforms such as `filter()`, `map()`, etc.

```
const map = new Map([
  ['key one', 'value one'],
  ['key two', 'value two'],
]);

// Loop through key-value-pairs
Array.from(map.entries()).map(([key, val]) => console.log(key, val));

// Loop through map keys
Array.from(map.keys()).map(key => console.log(key));

// Loop through values
Array.from(map.values()).map(value => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 5):

The callback to `$.each()` is passed the property name and the value, in that order. You're therefore trying to iterate over the property names in the inner call to `$.each()`. I think you want:

```
$.each(myMap, function (i, val) {
  $.each(val, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
    // ...
  });
});
```

In the inner loop, given an object like your map, the values are arrays. That's OK, but note that the "innerKey" values will all be numbers.

*edit* — Now once that's straightened out, here's the next problem:

```
    setTimeout(function () {

      // ...

    }, i * 6000);
```

The first time through that loop, "i" will be the string "partnr1".  Thus, that multiplication attempt will result in a `NaN`.  You can keep an external counter to keep track of the property count of the outer map:

```
var pcount = 1;
$.each(myMap, function(i, val) {
  $.each(val, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // ...
    }, pcount++ * 6000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By changing $.each(i... to $.each(val..  my code above is working in the way that its showing a result. But unfortunally its only showing the last result from the map, so its jumping straight to the final iteration.

Comment: @user2374903 no, it's not jumping to the last one, though it appears to be doing so. I hadn't looked closely at the "setTimeout" call, so I'll add to my answer.

Comment: By changing the pcount from 1 to 0 (which means it starts from the first loop) the code worked, but only as showing the models one by one. My mistake for not making this clear, the goal is to get all the models that correspond to that partnumer showing as a list beeing faded in.

Comment: OK: [you may want to look this over for future questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use iterators to do this. Maintain your own loop by incrementing a counter in the callback, and recursively calling the operation on the next item.

```
$.each(myMap, function(_, arr) {
    processArray(arr, 0);
});

function processArray(arr, i) {
    if (i >= arr.length) return;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#variant').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).text(i + "-" + arr[i]).fadeIn("slow");

            // Handle next iteration
            processArray(arr, ++i);
        });
    }, 6000);
}
```

---

Though there's a logic error in your code. You're setting the same container to more than one different value at (roughly) the same time. Perhaps you mean for each one to update its own container.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried you code, but you 're right about thats there 's a problem with the container. The code below works though, but here its only a single value array:

Comment: This looks like a nice way to do it.

Comment: $.each(jArray, function(i, val) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#reklame2').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).text(val).fadeIn("slow");
      });
     $('#reklame17').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).text(val).fadeIn("slow");
     
                });
            }, i * 6000);
   
        });

Comment: @user2374903: What is the intention? Should each `partnr` update a separate container, or are they all meant to run in sequence? Or should it be `partnr1[0] -> partnr2[0] -> partnr1[1] -> partnr2[1] -> etc`

Comment: Sorry for not making clear the object for the iteration. For each time the partnr shows up ALL the corrensponding models are going to be faded in as a list in that moment.

Answer (score 0):

We can use forEach Method available on maps From ES6 Version.

```js
var myMap =new Map([
    ["partnr1", ['modelA', 'modelB', 'modelC']],
    ["partnr2", ['modelA', 'modelB', 'modelC']]
]);

myMap.forEach(function(values,key){
  
  console.log(key);
  
  /*****Do something with the models***********/
  
  for(const [index,value] of values.entries()){
      console.log(`   ${key}[${index}] : ${value}`);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved using a javascript `Map` object. You simply iterate over the `Map`, using the fact that the map you're iterating over is included as an argument in each iteration call. Notice the `map` argument in the `forEach` function. This is the same `Map` object you're iterating over.

```
// Define the map
const myMap = new Map([
    ["key1", "value 1"],
    ["key2": "value 2"],
    ["key3": "value 3"]
])

// Iterate over the map, updating each value
myMap.forEach((value,key,map) => {
   map.set(key, value + "A")
})

/*
Result: myMap now looks like this:
[ 
    ["key1", "value 1A"],
    ["key2": "value 2A"],
    ["key3": "value 3A"]
]
/*
```