# Iterete thru map with [key, object] values

Tags: javascript

I have next map:

```
 const filter = new Map();

  filter.set('a1', {
    Day: 55,
    Type: 1,
  });

  filter.set('a2', {
    Day: 2,
    Type: 3,
  });
```

and I want to iterate thru it, by extracting only objects:

```
filter.values().map(({ Day, Type }) => {
  console.log(Day)
});
```

or

```
[...filter].map(({ Time, Type }) => {
  console.log(eventTime)
});
```

but I am getting error that map() is not function, or for second case it return Map item

p.s. I can't use for loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iterate through a map in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507866/iterate-through-a-map-in-javascript)

Comment: "*p.s. I can't use for loops.*" - why?! What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Map iterators don't have a `map` method ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)). You're probably looking for either [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach)

```
filter.forEach(({ Day, Type }) => {
  console.log(Day)
});
```

or a simple `for … of` loop over the iterator:

```
for (const { Day, Type } of filter.values()) {
  console.log(Day)
}
```

Comment: for some how I need to do it thru [...filter].map(( event ) => {
  console.log(event);
});

Comment: @Ted No, don't do that. You should not use `map` if you don't want to create an array but just execute some side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const filter = new Map();

  filter.set('a1', {
    Day: 55,
    Type: 1,
  });

  filter.set('a2', {
    Day: 2,
    Type: 3,
  });

for ( {Day,Type} of filter.values()) {
  console.log("Day: ",Day, "Type:",Type)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get and array of objects you can use spread syntax `...` on map values that returns `MapIterator`. Then you can use any array method like `forEach`.

```js
const filter = new Map();
filter.set('a1', { Day: 55, Type: 1 });
filter.set('a2', { Day: 2, Type: 3 });

console.log([...filter.values()])
```

Comment: It return Map item, but I need Day and Type of each item

Comment: @Ted This gives you an array of values so you can use `map` like this https://jsfiddle.net/f6wodsrc/