# React: How to iterate through dictionary

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Learning React and I was wondering how could I iterate through a dictionary. I come from python and theres a .items() method that can return key and value...is there a similar function in React? I want to set the values into a const and store them for future use. Heres what I have so far. (The reason I need this is because my JSON response gives an array which I already iterated through, but then a dictionary which I need to of course pull values from). Thanks so much for your time. Any response helps :)

JSX:

```
function Home(){
  
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const getData= ()=>{
    fetch('http://localhost:8070/api')
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson){
      console.log(myJson);
      setData(myJson)
    })
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])


  return (
    <div className="Home">
      {
        data?.results.map(result =>(
            <p class="text-nowrap bd-highlight" style={{width: "8rem"}}>{JSON.stringify(result.items)}</p> // HERES THE DICTIONARY
        ))
      }
    </div>
    )
  
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550693/8688902

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` collection:

```
new Map(fooArr.map(i => [i.name, i.surname]));
```

As [mdn says about `Map` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
> insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive
> values) may be used as either a key or a value.

An example:

```js
let fooArr = [
  { name: 'name 1', surname: 'surname 1' },
  { name: 'name 2', surname: 'surname 2' }
];

let result = new Map(fooArr.map(i => [i.name, i.surname]));
console.log(JSON.stringify([...result]));
```

As an alternative, you can use `Set` or just create simple object. Object has `key-value` too. Let me show an example:

```js
let fooArr = [
  { name: 'foo', surname: 'bar' },
  { name: 'hello', surname: 'world' }
];


let object = fooArr.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.name]: item.surname }), {});

console.log(object)
```

Comment: this is not wrong, but misleading, the user probably doesnt need to use `Map` or `Set`. And given how dictionaries work on Python, this can be extra misleading to someone with python background.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer. This React guide explains the arrays and how to use or set your keys for them: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
I would recommend making `<div>`s for each result or make a `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>` to store the individual items. Give each div or row a key and it is a lot easier to use it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` which is similar to `python` `.items`:

```js
const data = {a: 1, b: 2}

console.log(Object.entries(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with objects you can use `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()`, which do a similar thing than their similarly named python counterparts. (`keys()`, `values()`, `pairs()`)

```
const obj = { person: 'John' }
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) // ['person', 'John']
```

Some differences from python...

- Differently from python, those functions return Arrays.
- (python returns an iterable, which is not a list, and you may need to cast it to `list()` for indexed access).

Arrays are iterables (as lists are on Python), so you can write:

```js
// loop over iterable syntax, similar to python's for in
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {

}
```

Extra info on objects:

- On JS almost everything is an Object, so there is no difference on writing `obj.property` or `obj['property']`. On Python class instances and dictionaries require a bit different handling.
- JS Object keys can only be strings. If you pass a non string to an object key, it will be cast to a string;
- JS also has its `Map` and `Set` collections. Those classes have iterators of their own (instead of using `Object.X`, they have their own `.entries()` etc); You usually won't need to use `Map` and `Set` as JS Objects already cover most of the needs;